# How to send parameters in requests.get() with hashtag instead of question mark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

My goal is to make `requests.get()` understand that I want to use `#` as the query symbol instead of the default `?`.

Here is an example:

```
import requests

# our base url
url = 'https://www.example.com/search#'

# our query parameters
params = {
    'one_parameter' : 'one_value'
}

# making the request
response = requests.get(url, params = params)

# printing the url requested by requests.get()
print(response.url)
```

I was expecting this output:

```
https://www.example.com/search#one_parameter=one_value
```

Instead I got:

```
https://www.example.com/search?one_parameter=one_value
```

Two questions:

- Why did requests automatically removed the initial `#` ?
- How can I make understand requests that I want to use a `#` instead of a `?` as a query delimiter symbol?

**Update:**
I wanted to extract data from a LinkedIn search when the url gets really long, it switches to a `#` instead of a `?`.

Example of url:
`https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people#companyExcluded=Clarins%3A10116%2CEverlog%3A10473838%2CSisley%2520Paris%3A1055530%2CBMW%2520BAYERN%2520Bordeaux-Bassin%2520by%2520autosphere%2520(M%25C3%25A9rignac%2520-%2520La%2520Teste-de-Buch)%3A10667996%2COrange%3A1110%2CShiseido%3A11223%2Cmercedes%3A11235632%2CA26%2520architectures%3A11380777...` (and more)

And yes indeed it seems like some JavaScript is then using the fragment part to make further processes and eventually get the data.

I thus need to mimic the behavior of a browser.

Comment: what for, what is the purpose?

Comment: That simply isn't how HTTP works.  The part after a `#` is a *fragment identifier*; it's never sent to the server, it's just used by the browser to auto-scroll to a given element (and made available to JavaScript for possible further uses).  Since you're not actually using a browser (or running any JavaScript) here, including a fragment identifier in your URL would be completely pointless.

Comment: As @jasonharper says, get parameters (?x=y) go before the fragment (#abc) in the url, so `requests` must put your parameters before the #. The fragment is empty (ie it just has the #), so it doesn't (shouldn't) affect the web page. Thus, `requests` doesn't bother to put it back. With regards to your other question, about how to put parameters into the fragment, there's a few different options. You could go for something like `'&'.join('='.join(pair) for pair in params.items())`, including this string at the end of your url. NB: This is a very simple solution, and will not escape characters.

Comment: @Vova @jasonharper @Ed Ward Updated the question & context on why I want to do this. Ultimately even if I replace `?` by `#`it is not going to solve my issue. I need to mimic a web browser behavior to process the JavaScript. I thus delete the question.

Answer (score 5):

According to good old RFC the [URI syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3) is:

```
         foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
         \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
          |           |            |            |        |
       scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
          |   _____________________|__
         / \ /                        \
         urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

- `#` is a [fragment separator](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3.5)
- `?` is a [query separator](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#section-3.4)

So requests strictly do what you say, it generates query parameters via params key. When you need custom fragment do it yourself:

```py
fragments = {
    "one_parameter": "one_value",
}

fragment = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in fragments.items()])
response = requests.get(f"{url}#{fragment}")
```

Proper quoting may also be required, check `urllib.parse.quote`.
To simulate a user agent or browser, you can [read about its behavior](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#scroll-to-fragid) on fragments.